# can't extract any data with this code using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm just learning how to use scrapy but I'm having trouble running my first spider. This is my code but it doesn't extract any data! Could you please help me :)

```
    import scrapy

    class Housin(scrapy.Spider):
        name ='housin'
        star_urls = ['http://www.metrocuadrado.com/apartamento/venta/bogota/usado/']

        def parse (self,response):
            for href in response.css('a.data-details-id::attr(href)'):
                yield response.follow(href, self.parse_livi)

        def parse_livi(self,response):
            yield {
                'latitude': response.xpath('//input[@id="latitude"]/@value').extract_first(),
                'longitud': response.xpath('//input[@id="longitude"]/@value').extract_first(),
                'price': response.xpath('//dd[@class="important"]/text()').extract_first(),
                'Barrio_com': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Nombre com&uacute;n del barrio "]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
                'Barrio_cat': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Nombre del barrio catastral"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
                'Estrato': response.xpath('.//dl/dt[h3/text()="Estrato"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/h4/text()').extract_first(),
                'id': response.xpath('//input[@id="propertyId"]/@value').extract_first()
                }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the scrape log to check it's crawling and following URLs and that your path statements are correct... Short of someone debugging this for you -  you could localise it yourself easily enough - look at the logs, put some prints in for each of the items you're trying to extract etc... :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your scraper doesn't start at all. Below

```
star_urls = ['http://www.metrocuadrado.com/apartamento/venta/bogota/usado/']
```

should be

```
start_urls = ['http://www.metrocuadrado.com/apartamento/venta/bogota/usado/']
```

That typo (missing `t`) causes scrapy to not find any starting url and hence the scraping doesn't start at all

Comment: thank you so much!! I'm sorry I'm new to programming